# server sent event connections not closing on page change in react

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, react-hooks, server-sent-events

I am creating a fullstack application using springboot and react. The backend application exposes an API which frontend connects to using EventSource. My backend data that is sent to the frontend is a Java object with parameters : time, pushcode, successes, failures through server sent events.

The backend would have a stack of the described java object which needs to be pushed to frontend whenever another java object is added to the stack.

Currently for testing purpose, I am generating the java object with random values and sending the stack to frontend every 4 seconds and duration of SSE connection is infinite until page is changed. This is working fine on frontend IF I do not refresh the page or the url does not change to another page and I go back to the homepage

Currently I am getting a result like attached image after refresh or changing url and going back. Please note the gap in time intervals. The difference should be 4 seconds but it's like another connection got opened.

[image]

**Frontend**:

React code:

```
const WorkingSmsesEvent = () => {
  const executedSmsListener = useStore((state) => state.executedSmsListener)
  const setExecutedSmsListener = useStore((state) => state.setExecutedSmsListener)
  
  const [data, setData] = useState(null)
  let eventSource = undefined;


  const handleMessage = (event) => {
    const msg = JSON.parse(event.data);
    console.log("addEventListener Progress:", event.target.readyState);
    setData(msg)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!executedSmsListener) {
      eventSource = new EventSource("http://localhost:9090/api/dashboard/subscribe", { withCredentials: true});
      

      window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        eventSource.close();
        eventSource.removeEventListener("Progress", handleMessage)
        setExecutedSmsListener(false);
        return true;
      };

      eventSource.addEventListener("Progress", handleMessage);

      eventSource.onerror = (event) => {
        if (event.target.readyState === EventSource.CLOSED) {
          console.log('SSE closed (' + event.target.readyState + ')')
        }
        eventSource.close();
      }

      eventSource.onopen = (event) => {
        setExecutedSmsListener(true);
      }
      

      return () => {
        setExecutedSmsListener(false);
        eventSource.close();   
        eventSource.removeEventListener("Progress", handleMessage)
      }
    }
  }, [])


  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col'>
        <div className='flex flex-wrap'>
        {
            data?.map((item, id) => (
            <div key={id}>
                <Cards extend={false} data={item}/>
            </div>
            ))
        }
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

zustand store

```
import { create } from 'zustand'

export const useStore = create((set) => ({
 
  executedSmsListener: false,
  setExecutedSmsListener: executedSmsListener => set((state) => ({ executedSmsListener }))
}))
```

**Backend**

Controller

```
@GetMapping("/subscribe")
    public ResponseEntity<SseEmitter> subscribeSSE() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        final SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter((long)-1);
        service.addEmitter(emitter);
        service.subscribeExecutedSms();
        emitter.onCompletion(() -> service.removeEmitter(emitter));
        emitter.onTimeout(() -> service.removeEmitter(emitter));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(emitter, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Service

```
public void subscribeExecutedSms() throws IOException {
        List<SseEmitter> deadEmitters = new ArrayList<>();
        Random num = new Random();
        
        scheduled = taskScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            ExecutedSms executed = new ExecutedSms(TIME_FORMATTER.format(new Date()), num.nextInt(20) + 2, num.nextInt(3), num.nextInt(10) + 115);
            execSmsList.add(executed);
            execSmsEmitters.forEach(emitter -> {
                try {
                    emitter.send(SseEmitter.event().name("Progress")
                            .data(execSmsList));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    deadEmitters.add(emitter);
                }
            });
            if (execSmsList.size() == 8) {
                execSmsList.clear();
            }
            execSmsEmitters.removeAll(deadEmitters);
        }, (long)4000);
    }
```

I am not sure why another connection is opening up since I did close the connection on page change. I can provide more information regarding this if required. Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to figure out the problem ?

Comment: Ah yes, problem was that even if i changed the url path in frontend and even closed the eventsource, the backend was still running a scheduled task on every time subscribe was called. This was never closed on backend so the way i wrote the code, i needed to create a separate API that would stop the scheduled task also apart from closing eventsource. However, this created another problem when there are multiple users. Currently I implemented an Observer pattern where the SSEvent is created on backend but new users only subscribe and unsubscribe to the API. Hence there is only 1 instance of SSE.